# Is it possible to fix a distorted laminated chair leg? [bent-wood lamination]

Tags: furniture, bending

I have an armchair that, according to the manufacturer, is made of moulded layer-glued wood veneer (IKEA Poang).

After several years the chair is tipping to the left. As seen from the picture below, the left leg/arm is sitting 2 cm lower than the right.

I tried spraying with water, applying heat with a heat gun and then pulling the lower leg using force. That evened the legs but only temporarily.

Is it possible to salvage it?

[image: IKEA Poang]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the shape of the leg should be possible because the bend you require is not extreme. Because of the glue joints a larger bend may be impossible, but a small change in radius is not hard.

Do not use water or you will damage finish, just use heat. If the heat gun is your only heat source you need to heat for much longer. When enough wood is hot **bend leg more than is required** using clamps or rope/straps and **leave to cool overnight**.

But if the use that caused the distortion remains, the chair will be tipping to the left again in a few months I think.

Comment: The heat gun heats up to 600 C and it left a little darkening to the areas it was applied (only the two corners). Also, I did stack weight plates beneath the arm to keep it in an expanded position and let it sit overnight. Oh well...

Comment: Ikea's warranty department has been pretty good to me in the past. It’s worth asking.

Comment: I would guess heating the other and bending it down to match the one that settled, might last longer...

Comment: I think the last sentence is the key one. If someone is sitting crooked in the chair (or "stuff" is stacked in it, whatever) putting more weight on one side than the other, then any repair that gets the chair level will simply be undone again by the uneven use. If there was a manufacturing defect that led to the sagging, then it will probably still be there, and will sag more in the future.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, after *several years*???

Comment: @Nick, yeah localised heating always runs a risk of changing the colour. It may not be the wood, it could be water forced under the finish in which case if you're lucky it could lessen in time, but I wouldn't count on it going away entirely without intervention (which may or may not be worth it given the chair and its other issue). You were starting behind the 8-ball here, heating something that already has finish on using a heat source this hot is fraught with danger. In normal circumstances you'd rely on post-bend finishing work (scraping or sanding) to remove any scorching that might occur.

Comment: @Graphus — I honestly don’t know… that’s why I suggested asking. I get the point that they don’t have any actual obligation.